# Multi repond Power bi

Tags: powerbi

How can I visually represent the responses to multiple-choice questions in Power BI using existing data, where each column corresponds to a choice, each row represents an entry, and cells contain either 1 or 0 based on whether the user chose or did not choose a particular option? I aim to create the visualization without the need to create a new table.

i want a solution other than create an new table and build a relationship as this take a lot of time when flirting and loading